# Problema al trazar serie de puntos en Python

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Actualmente estoy retomando Python para realizar un trabajo y me encuentro replicando la siguiente gráfica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que utilicé es el siguiente:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1=[-0.196,-0.103,0.103]
x2=[-0.750,1.750,1.770]
x3=[-0.877,-0.701,-0.598]
x4=[-0.201,-0.098,0.250]

y1=[0.198,0.124,0.251]
y2=[-0.849,-0.552,-0.503]
y3=[-0.120,-0.446,-0.495]
y4=[0.845,0.796,0.695]

x_c=[-0.456,-0.456,-0.441,-0.393,-0.344,-0.339,-0.228,-0.157,-0.083,0.004,0.081,0.217,0.222,0.299,0.323,0.323,0.352]
y_c=[0.540,0.381,0.617,0.207,0.138,0.830,0.062,0.978,0.040,1.019,0.098,0.928,0.217,0.343,0.777,0.400,0.597]

plt.xlim(-1,2)
plt.ylim(-1,1)

plt.xticks(np.arange(-1, 2 + 1, 1), fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(np.arange(-1, 1 + 1, 1), fontsize=12)

plt.scatter(x1,y1, marker='s', edgecolor='black', color='lightblue', s=100)
plt.scatter(x2,y2, marker='o', edgecolor='black', color='purple', s=100)
plt.scatter(x3,y3, marker='^', edgecolor='black', color='red', s=100)
plt.scatter(x4,y4, marker='v', edgecolor='black', color='lightgreen', s=100)

plt.plot(x_c,y_c)

plt.legend(['CK','DCS','TT','TT+CK'], loc='upper right', edgecolor='black')

plt.xlabel('NMDS2', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('NMDS1', fontsize=12)

for pos in ['right', 'top']: 
    plt.gca().spines[pos].set_visible(False)
    
for axis in ['left','bottom']:
   plt.gca().spines[axis].set_linewidth(1.5)

plt.show()

plt.savefig('3.3.2.png')
```

Al ejecutar el código me sale lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo la serie de puntos x_c,y_c de manera que esta quede como se muestra en la figura inicial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

La forma más fácil de hacerlo es utilizar [`matplotlib.patches.Ellipse`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Ellipse.html) ya que si quieres hacerlo por puntos, como en tu pregunta, vas a tener que repasar las fórmulas de la elipse y obtener los puntos "x, y"

Ejemplo:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Ellipse

x1=[-0.196,-0.103,0.103]
x2=[-0.750,1.750,1.770]
x3=[-0.877,-0.701,-0.598]
x4=[-0.201,-0.098,0.250]

y1=[0.198,0.124,0.251]
y2=[-0.849,-0.552,-0.503]
y3=[-0.120,-0.446,-0.495]
y4=[0.845,0.796,0.695]

plt.xlim(-1,2)
plt.ylim(-1,1)

plt.xticks(np.arange(-1, 2 + 1, 1), fontsize=12)
plt.yticks(np.arange(-1, 1 + 1, 1), fontsize=12)

plt.scatter(x1,y1, marker='s', edgecolor='black', color='lightblue', s=100)
plt.scatter(x2,y2, marker='o', edgecolor='black', color='purple', s=100)
plt.scatter(x3,y3, marker='^', edgecolor='black', color='red', s=100)
plt.scatter(x4,y4, marker='v', edgecolor='black', color='lightgreen', s=100)

#Crear elipse
ax = plt.gca()
ellipse = Ellipse(xy=(-0.05, 0.5), width=0.8, height=1.00, angle=-10, edgecolor='r', fc='None', lw=2)
ax.add_patch(ellipse)



plt.legend(['CK','DCS','TT','TT+CK'], loc='upper right', edgecolor='black')

plt.xlabel('NMDS2', fontsize=12)
plt.ylabel('NMDS1', fontsize=12)

for pos in ['right', 'top']: 
    plt.gca().spines[pos].set_visible(False)
    
for axis in ['left','bottom']:
    plt.gca().spines[axis].set_linewidth(1.5)

plt.show()
```

Esto crea la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Gráfica]

Otra opción sin usar `Ellipse` es utilizar la función `plot` pero hay que calcular la elipse, un ejemplo genérico:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from math import pi

u=1.     #posición del centro en x
v=0.5    #posición del centro en y
a=2.     #radio en x
b=1.5    #radio en y

t = np.linspace(0, 2*pi, 100)
plt.plot( u+a*np.cos(t) , v+b*np.sin(t) )
plt.grid(color='lightgray',linestyle='--')
plt.show()
```

Esto dibuja la siguiente gráfica:

[image: Elipse]